# How to pull information from an object from an API call?

Tags: python, api, dataframe, object, stock

I'm trying to parse data from an API call that is returning an object I'm not familiar with. I'm making a call for all tradable assets (equities) using lpaca.markets [Assets](https://alpaca.markets/docs/api-documentation/api-v2/assets/). the API provides 9,322 assets in the form of their asset entity.

```
Asset({'class': 'us_equity',
       'easy_to_borrow': True,
       'exchange': 'NASDAQ',
       'id': 'ea7afd19-72b9-48cf-9f8b-1d9738870a24',
       'marginable': True,
       'name': 'IEC Electronics Corp. Common Stock',
       'shortable': True,
       'status': 'active',
       'symbol': 'IEC',
       'tradable': True})]
```

I want to convert the dictionary inside the Asset object into a 9,322 row  pandas dataframe. When I try to do this, I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Asset' object has no attribute 'Asset'
```

or

```
TypeError: 'Asset' object is not subscriptable
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull items from the Asset object using:

```
i.__getattr__('symbol')
```

Then able to add them to my dataframe with:

```
.append()
```

However, this is a bit slow. is there a faster way than append?